# problem with countdown using ```range()``` function-python3.8.0

Tags: python-3.x

coding language: python 3.8.0. interactive shell.
code:

```
else:
        print('INCORECT PASSWORD.')
        print('LOCKING DEVICE IN 30 SECONDES.')
        lockdownperiod = 30
        for lockdownperiod in range(30, 1):
            print('DEVICE LOCK IN: ' + lockdownperiod + ' SECONDES')
            lockdownperiod - 1
            time.sleep(1)
        if lockdownperiod == 0:
            lock()
```

note: this is a code snippet. you may notice that defined functions are not defined. also, please note the `else` statement. the code is incomplete.
note: please pay attention to lines 2-8.
context:
so i am trying to make a countdown of 30 secondes with the code snippet above,
but there is a problem:

the output that I get is:

```
INCORRECT PASSWORD.
DEVICE LOCK IN 30 SECONDES.
```

then it stops.
how do I make it countdown?

Comment: Your code has a couple issues. You define `lockdownperiod` both before and at the start of your for loop, which likely cause issues down the line. The biggest issue is your range is descending, which you can only do if you define a negative step i.e. `range(30,1,-1)`. As it is, you aren't ever entering your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the step number:

```
for i in range (30, 1, -1):
    ...
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range for more information

Comment: thankes, it workes, I just have to resolve a STR-INT issue in my program.